# Задать директиву в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Необходимо сделать ссылку из http://site.ru/index.php?act=register в такой вид: http://site.ru/register

Прописываю в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /site/index.php?act=$1 [L]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что неправильно?

Comment: Замените  

    /site/index.php?act=$1
на  

    index.php?act=$1

Comment: Может быть само выражение неправильное?
Ошибку не выкидывает, но и не выдает нужную страницу.
К примеру если сделать вот так RewriteRule ^act/([^/]*)$ index.php?act=$1 [L] то все в норме, но адрес выглядит так: 
http://site.ru/act/register

Comment: Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 1):

> > Может быть само выражение неправильное? Ошибку не выкидывает, но и не выдает нужную страницу. К примеру если сделать вот так RewriteRule ^act/([^/]*)$ index.php?act=$1 [L] то все в норме, но адрес выглядит так: http://site.ru/act/register

Конечно не верно, в приведенном случае будет: index.php?act=act

В регулярном выражении вы указали - считываем символы ДО первого /

http://site.ru/act/register - тут до вервого / будет **act**

Comment: Пишу так: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?act=$1 [L]
Получилось почти как нужно (http://site.ru/register/), но как сделать окончание строки без "/" в конце?